# Excel Slicer reverse sort order when using Power Pivot "Sort By Column"

Tags: excel, powerpivot, slicers

I have a bit of a strange one that I need help with.

I am using Power Pivot within Excel to build my data model, which consists of 100K+ rows.
I am sorting the **"reference number"** column by the **"total sale price"** column, so I can order by the total value.  This all works well.

However,  when I use a slicer, and set the item sorting to use **"data source order"**, it displays the reference numbers by the lowest sales price to the highest.    I want it to show the opposite way, **"Highest sales price"** first,  as that is the most important.

No matter what I do in Power pivot to change the order of the "Total sales price (high to low, or low to high)  the slicer does not change.

If I remove the "Sort by column" sorting,  it goes back to the reference number ordering, so I know it sort of works.

As the Total sales price value is not a sequential value, I don't think I can use an index column.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

DD

Comment: You could add a column to rank Total sales, i.e. with 1 being highest, etc., then use that for the Sort by Column.

Comment: Would I not have to keep manually extending or updating that column every time the dataset changes/grows?

Comment: A DAX Calculated Column would respond to changes in your dataset.

Comment: Though the ranking column would not respond to any filtering of the data, which may be undesirable for you.

Comment: There will be other filtering going on, based on salesman and time period.   But out of interest,  How, where and what DAX query would I need roughly (Not done DAX queries before).

Comment: Figured it out.   I used the RANKX function within a DAX Calculated Column.    Thanks for pointing me in the right direction with your original suggesting.

Comment: Sure, just be aware that that Calculated Column will not respond to your slicers/filters.

Answer (score 1):

To post the answer I used based off @Jos-wolley suggestion.

I used the RANKX function in a calculated column

Rank all rows as Column =
RANKX(
'Table',
'Table'[My Value]
)